# IIS: make hostname point to website

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, hostname, .net, bindings

I am deploying to my .net project to host.domain.com/Default Web Site/ProjectName.

I would like to make it so that the URL "host.domain.com" points to my application.

I suspect I don't have the bindings set correctly, but I can't figure what I need to do. Right now entering "host.domain.com" takes me to the default IIS screen, and I can only access my project via host.domain.com/ProjectName.

What do the bindings on Default Web Site need to be to make it point to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binding won't work here.  Bindings don't do redirects to other paths in a url, bindings just take hostnames, IP addresses, SSL certs, etc and direct them to a certain web site on your server.  What you need is either

- to publish your app to the root of your site (I'm assuming that's not an option)

or

- create a rewrite rule to redirect requests.  You'll need the URL rewrite extension installed to do this.  It's available [**here**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: Thanks. I created a new web site IIS published my application to the root of this site. That did the trick.

Comment: Oh good, that was an option!  Glad it's working for you.